# how can execute nagios commands from command line in linux

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, nagios

I am using nagios o centos server and i only want to monitor the localhost only.

I have defined my service like this

```
define service{
 host_name  localhost
 service_description Site1Service
 check_command  check_http-site1
 use   generic-service
 notification_interval 1440
}
```

and

command like this in commands.cfg

```
define command{
 command_name check_http-site1
 command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H site1.dreaddomain.com
}
```

I am getting critical error in there. so i want to check from command line if that service is running or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su - nagios -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H site1.dreaddomain.com'
```

Comment: No , i want to check `check_http-site1` not `check_http`. that i know it work

Comment: `check_http-site1` is just a command name that actually runs the above command as the `nagios` user.

Comment: yes but i want to know if that is working or not , or i have messed with something

Comment: Have you tried the above command?

Comment: yes that is working , but my new command was not working , so i wanted to know how to check that

Comment: _Re-schedule the next check of this service_ then take a look at the `nagios.log` or even `nagios.debug` to see what happens.

Comment: But my main question still remians that how to test commands written in `command.cfg` from command line not the `plugins`. something like `command check_http-site1`  just to see if that works or not

Comment: Increase the debug level to at least 256 (Commands) or 2048 (Macros), then restart the Nagios, force a new check, and take a look at `nagios.debug`.